# Desenhar texto na DBGrid

Tags: delphi

Olá. Estou tentando implementar um recurso visual, mas estou apanhando demais com o Canvas e posicionamento. A ideia, é colocar um texto na DBGrid informando que não encontrou registros, caso, a pesquisa retorne vazio, algo como na imagem abaixo. Tentei escrever com o Canvas, mas não consegui o resultado esperado, alguém poderia me ajudar, ou tem alguma outra ideia de como fazer isso? Grato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se existir uma outra forma sem ser com canvas, aceito sugestões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O componente da DevExpress TcxGrid, vem com essa opção nativa.

No entanto você poderia fazer algo simples usando a imaginação.

**Apenas Sugestão**

Você poderia usar penas uma Panel com as seguintes propriedades:

Panel cor  = branca
BevelOuter = bvNone
caption    =  Não há dados

E no seu Before você manipula apenas o panel, visible True ou False

Se quiser pronto a opção do DBgrid com o panel basta copiar(Ctrl + C) o código abaixo e dar Ctrl+V no seu Form:

```
object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
  Left = 72
  Top = 320
  Width = 377
  Height = 145
  TabOrder = 5
  TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
  TitleFont.Height = -11
  TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
  TitleFont.Style = []
end
object Panel1: TPanel
  Left = 167
  Top = 360
  Width = 185
  Height = 41
  BevelOuter = bvNone
  Caption = 'N'#227'o h'#225' dados'
  Color = clWhite
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = cl3DDkShadow
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  ParentBackground = False
  ParentFont = False
  TabOrder = 6
end
```

**Plus, para centralizar o panel**

```
Procedure CentralizarPanel(AForm: TForm; APanel: TPanel);
begin
  APanel.Left := (AForm.ClientWidth div 2) - (APanel.Width div 2);
  APanel.Top := (AForm.ClientHeight div 2) - (APanel.Height div 2);
 
  APanel.Update;
  AForm.Update;
end;
```

Resultado :

[image: DbGrid com a mensagem]

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certo.